_RTLENTRY, _EXPFUNC are not defined in the new C++ Builder's "Windows 64-bit (Modern)" platform?
Suppose I have a function like this in my project ("Windows 64-bit" platform):
void * _RTLENTRY _EXPFUNC DoSomething(void) {

Now I want to migrate my project to the new "Windows 64-bit (Modern)" platform. The above mentioned line will fail with this error:

[bcc64x Error] Unit1.cpp(17): expected ';' after top level declarator

The _RTLENTRY and _EXPFUNC are defined in the _defs.h file under the \include\windows\crtl\ folder.
If I add this line:
#include <_defs.h>

The compiler will complain that the _defs.h file is not found.
If I copy the definitions from the _defs.h file into my own source, then the error will be gone.
#if defined(_WIN64)
#define _RTLENTRY
#define _USERENTRY
#else
#define _RTLENTRY  __cdecl
#define _USERENTRY __cdecl
#endif

What am I missing? How should I resolve this?

I don't think you should be including _defs.h directly and I don't think the new clang enhanced toolchain will include it or needs those defines in any case.  If you just define them empty and compile in 32 bit mode (with the clang enhanced compiler), does it still work?

I would ignore _defs.h exists and just use #ifndef in my own code: #ifndef _RTLENTRY #define _RTLENTRY #endif #ifndef _EXPFUNC #define _EXPFUNC #endif. __cdecl has no meaning in 64bit and is ignored by 64bit compilers.
